# Redirect from html (js) to angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, xmlhttprequest

I need to redirect from a simple page in html and js to an angular app.
In the js i wrote this:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://ANGULAR.it:4200", true ); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("TOKEN", "TOKEN");
xmlHttp.send( null );
```

That request give me this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ANGULAR:4200/' from origin 'http://JS.it' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

So, I don't know how set CORS in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do nothing. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) is a problem that you can resolve only in backend. You need to create a filter that read the request and it understands if the request can be process or not. in angular you set only the header about this request

Comment: So I can't do a request from js to angular with an auth header? Because I need it for that. There is another way to produce a request with a token? Not in POST payload or GET query.